# Simple_form style the collection_label's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have this simple_form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
                    <%= f.error_notification %>
                    <%= f.association :orderstatus, :label => false, :include_blank => false, :input_html => { :class => 'order-status' } , :as => :radio, :label_html => { :style => "background-color:black;" } %>
                    <%= f.button :submit, :value => 'Update', :class => 'button grey small' %>

                <% end %>
```

And it creates this: http://d.pr/9Bqd  In the database I also have a field `color` which is a hex code for the background color I want of each status.  Any idea how to pass this hex code onto each background label color?!  I've tried for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing it in like this...

```
 # assuming "hex" is stored in the order model. Any variable should work
 :label_html => { :style => "background-color:##{@order.hex};" }
```

If not, please respond with your results